# R - create dynamic indicator columns from values in character columns

Tags: r

I have data that looks like this:

```
library(dplyr)

d<-data.frame(ID=c(1,1,2,3,3,4), Quality=c("Good", "Bad", "Ugly", "Good", "Good", "Ugly"), Area=c("East", "North", "North", "South", "East", "North"))
```

What I'd like to do is create one new column for each unique value in Quality and populate it with whether the ID matches that value and then aggregate the ID's. I want to do the same for Area.

This is what I have for when **Quality == Good**:

```
d$Quality.Good <- 0
d$Quality.Good[d$Quality=="Good"] <- 1

e <- d %>% 
      group_by(ID) %>%
      summarise(n=n(), MAX.Quality.Good = max(Quality.Good))
e
```

**Output**

```
A tibble: 4 x 3
 ID       MAX.Quality.Good
  <dbl>    <dbl>
1     1        1
2     2        0
3     3        1
4     4        0
```

**Is it possible to build a function that will loop through each character column and build an indicator column for Good, Bad, Ugly, North, East, South instead of copy pasting the above many more times?**

Here's where I'm stuck:

```
library(stringr)

#vector of each Quality
e <-d %>% 
  group_by(Quality) %>%
  summarise(n=n()) %>%
  select(Quality)
e<-as.data.frame(e)

#create new column names
f <- str_c(names(e),".",e[,1]) 

#initialize list of new columns
d[f] <- 0

#I'm stuck after this...
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do this in `base R` using `table` by replicating the 'ID' column by the number of columns of dataset minus 1, and `paste`ing the column names with the `unlist`ed values (excluding the 'ID' column)

```
table(rep(d$ID, 2), paste0(names(d)[-1][col(d[-1])], unlist(d[-1])))
#       AreaEast AreaNorth AreaSouth QualityBad QualityGood QualityUgly
#  1        1         1         0          1           1           0
#  2        0         1         0          0           0           1
#  3        1         0         1          0           2           0
#  4        0         1         0          0           0           1
```

---

or with `tidyverse`, `gather` into 'long' format, `unite` the 'key', 'val' columns to a single column, get the `distinct` rows, and `spread` into 'wide' format after creating a column of 1s.

```
library(tidyverse)
gather(d, key, val, -ID) %>%
   unite(kv, key, val) %>% 
   distinct %>%
   mutate(n = 1) %>% 
   spread(kv, n, fill = 0)
#ID Area_East Area_North Area_South Quality_Bad Quality_Good Quality_Ugly
#1  1         1          1          0           1            1            0
#2  2         0          1          0           0            0            1
#3  3         1          0          1           0            1            0
#4  4         0          1          0           0            0            1
```

Comment: I went with the 2nd solution because I'm more familiar with the functions used though I couldn't see how to put them together like that. FYI the first solution has a '2' in row 3 of the 'QualityGood' column.

Answer (score 1):

**1) Base R** Create the model matrix for each column (using function `make_mm`) and bind them together as a data frame `m`.  Finally aggregate on `ID`.  No packages are used.

```
make_mm <- function(nm, data) model.matrix(~ . - 1, data[nm])
m <- do.call("data.frame", lapply(names(d)[-1], make_mm, d))
with(d, aggregate(. ~ ID, m, max))
```

giving:

```
  ID QualityBad QualityGood QualityUgly AreaEast AreaNorth AreaSouth
1  1          1           1           0        1         1         0
2  2          0           0           1        0         1         0
3  3          0           1           0        1         0         1
4  4          0           0           1        0         1         0
```

**2) dplyr/purrr** This could alternately be written as the following which is close to the code in the question but generalizes to all required columns.  Note that here we make model data frames using `make_md` rather than making model matrices with `make_mm`.  Also note that the dot in `group_by(m, ID = .$ID)` refers to `d` and not to `m`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

make_md <- function(nm, data) {
  data %>% 
    select(nm) %>% 
    model.matrix(~ . - 1, .) %>% 
    as.data.frame
}

d %>% {
  m <- map_dfc(names(.)[-1], make_md, .)
  group_by(m, ID = .$ID) %>%
  summarize_all(max) %>%
  ungroup
}
```